# Why am i getting this error when i try to add foreign keys on Invoice table?

Tags: php, laravel, database, migration

I have two tables `users` and `invoices`. This is the `up` function for the `users` migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('comentarii');

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This is the `up` function for the `invoices` migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->refferences('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('InvoiceNumber');
        $table->dateTime('date');
        $table->string('serviceInvoiced');
        
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

All I am trying to do is to make a one to many relationship as in a user can have multiple invoices.

Here is the `User` model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getInvoices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);
    }
}
```

Here is the `Invoice` model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded=[];

    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I watched multiple tutorials already. Here are the errors that im getting:

[image: errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns need to be of the same type. `id()` is an alias of `bigIncrements()`, so

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
```

should be

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

Also note: it's `->references('id')`, not `->refferences('id')`

More on [Available Column Types](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-column-types)

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. You have a typo in your migration statement
2. `$this->id()` make `unsignedBigInteger` so `user_id` should be `unsignedBigInteger`

Alter you migration lines to this:

```
 $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
 $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); //references not refferences
```